# Will there be a @types/jest version 27?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, definitelytyped

Every other Jest related package I've seen already is version 27, except this one. I'm not sure if that's intentional. Jest documentation [states](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript)

> For @types/* modules it's recommended to try to match the version of the associated module. For example, if you are using 26.4.0 of jest then using 26.4.x of @types/jest is ideal. In general, try to match the major (26) and minor (4) version as closely as possible.

I wasn't sure if the 27 work was blocked by making sure `@jest/globals` is ready to be used as the dependency in DefinitelyTyped (if I'm understanding the [PR discussion](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/44365) correctly). Or if it was because there were no type changes needed for 27 release (seems kinda unlikely to me). Maybe it's just no one has gotten to it yet.

If it is just a case of no one getting to it yet, as a follow-up, is there an easy way to know what types need updated?

Comment: I thought this was the only time this had happened, but it turns out it's happened once before, with version 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest folks confirmed 44365 is NOT blocking @types/jest 27. But they didn't know the status of @types/jest update. I don't believe any of the Jest contributors are also Jest DefinitelyTyped contributors.

[A question](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/54606) posted in GitHub confirmed that this was just a case of the update not being done yet. But there is now a [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/55013) to update the types.

Krisztián Balla's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428061/160256) describes how to find changes between versions that might require changes to the types. Unfortunately, there's no easier way to do that, and there is nowhere you can look to know if the Jest DefinitelyTyped maintainers anticipate any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DefinitelyTyped is not related to Jest. Actually DefinitelyTyped is maintained by folks of the TypeScript team at Microsoft and of course a lot of volunteers.

The types at DefinitelyTyped document the external API of JavaScript libraries.

To see what has changed one would have to compare the APIs:

- **Current (27.0)**: https://jestjs.io/docs/api
- **26.x**: https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/api

A list of changes is available in the change log here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2700

One would have to skim through all this and update the types accordingly.